# Direct sum $\Rightarrow$ Direct Integral, Tensor product $\Rightarrow$?

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Is there a way to define a tensor product over a measure space(=index set) with a continuous measure for Hilbert spaces?

For the sum we have the notion of a direct integral, here.

Comment: I doubt there is such a thing. Out of curiosity: why would one want to have such a construction? I can see some (although not much) need for countable tensor products. The utility and applicability of such a construction eludes me. I ask this also in order to clarify your intentions: what kind of properties would you like this gadget to have? Do you want just *something* you could call a tensor product or do you have an application in mind?

Comment: Not really an application, but some ideas what it'd be. In the theory of stochastic processes, the $\sigma$ algebra often refine with continuous time. For certain processes, I'd think that this can be interpreted as such an infinite tensor product. I want a purely abstract definition here not involving the notion of stochastic processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Continuous tensor products" have been applied in certain areas such as quantum stochastic processes and quantum field theory, see for example the following [paper](http://www.math.berkeley.edu/~arveson/oldDvi/endoqftsurvey.pdf) by Arveson. I think that the definitions in [Vershik and Tsilevich](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304282)  are more transparent (in this article the continuous tensor product is mainly referred to as a "factorization").

The basic object which possesses a continuous tensor product structure is the Fock space. However, one can find in the references of Vershik examples of non-Fock factorizations, 
see for example the following [talk](http://mathit.unco.edu/vi2011/talks/vi-vershik.pdf). A further application is in the [representation theory of current algebras](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.1387).

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected to a certain extent. However, I may be misreading what Arveson says, but isn't his point in section 4 that *product systems* may heuristically  be thought of "continuous tensor products" but *"While this heuristic picture is often useful, one must be careful not to push it too far."*

Comment: I think that in the actual work by Averson (the reference I gave is just a lecture note) and also by Vershik (and also by others), the notion of continuous tensor product is rigorously defined.

Comment: Thanks! [These lecture notes](http://math.berkeley.edu/~arveson/Dvi/prodsys.pdf) (Def. 2.1) make the analogy still a bit clearer than the set of notes you linked to, I think. Very interesting.

Comment: I think Ron Blei's book has some info on the subject too.

Comment: I am actually suprised that the answer is yes! Thx.